# Fetch data from superhero api using axios react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, axios

I need to fetch data from https://superheroapi.com/ using Axios in a React Application. I did not have any warning messages in console but still the data is not fetched. The page loader is loading but there is no response.

Here is my code.

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  InputGroup,
  Input,
  InputGroupAddon,
  Button,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Spinner
} from 'reactstrap';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import BookCard from './BookCard.jsx';
function App() {
  // States
  const [maxResults, setMaxResults] = useState(10);
  const [startIndex, setStartIndex] = useState(1);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  // Handle Search
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    setLoading(**false**);
    if (maxResults > 40 || maxResults < 1) {
      toast.error('max results must be between 1 and 40');
    } else {
      axios
        .get(
           
          `https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/my-api-key/search/${query}&maxResults=${maxResults}&startIndex=${startIndex}`

        )
        .then(res => {
          if (startIndex >= res.data.totalItems || startIndex < 1) {
            toast.error(
              `max reults must be between 1 and ${res.data.totalItems}`
            );
          } else {
            if (res.data.items.length > 0) {
              setCards(res.data.items);
              setLoading(false);
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          setLoading(true);
          console.log(err.response);
        });
    }
  };
  // Main Show Case
  const mainHeader = () => {
    return (
      <div className='main-image d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column'>
        {/* Overlay */}
        <div className='filter'></div>
        <h1
          className='display-2 text-center text-white mb-3'
          style={{ zIndex: 2 }}
        >
          Search
        <div style={{ width: '60%', zIndex: 2 }}>
          <InputGroup size='lg' className='mb-3'>
            <Input
              placeholder='Book Search'
              value={query}
              onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            />
            <InputGroupAddon addonType='append'>
              <Button color='secondary' onClick={handleSubmit}>
                <i className='fas fa-search'></i>
              </Button>
            </InputGroupAddon>
          </InputGroup>
          <div className='d-flex text-white justify-content-center'>
            <FormGroup >
              <Label for='maxResults'>Max Results</Label>
              <Input
                type='number'
                id='maxResults'
                placeholder='Max Results'
                value={maxResults}
                onChange={e => setMaxResults(e.target.value)}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className='ml-5'>
              <Label for='startIndex'>Start Index</Label>
              <Input
                type='number'
                id='startIndex'
                placeholder='Start Index'
                value={startIndex}
                onChange={e => setStartIndex(e.target.value)}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const handleCards = () => {
    if (loading) {
      return (
        <div className='d-flex justify-content-center mt-3'>
          <Spinner style={{ width: '3rem', height: '3rem' }} />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      const items = cards.map((item, i) => {
        let thumbnail = '';
        if (item.volumeInfo.imageLinks) {
          thumbnail = item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
        }

        return (
          <div className='col-lg-4 mb-3' key={item.id}>
            <BookCard
              thumbnail={thumbnail}
              title={item.volumeInfo.name}
        
            />
          </div>
        );
      });
      return (
        <div className='container my-5'>
          <div className='row'>{items}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className='w-100 h-100'>
      {mainHeader()}
      {handleCards()}
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my json output when I run the url(https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/my-api-key/search/batman) in my browser

```
{
    "response": "success",
    "results-for": "batman",
    "results": [{
        "id": "69",
        "name": "Batman",
        "powerstats": {
            "intelligence": "81",
            "strength": "40",
            "speed": "29",
            "durability": "55",
            "power": "63",
            "combat": "90"
        },
        "biography": {
            "full-name": "Terry McGinnis",
            "alter-egos": "No alter egos found.",
            "aliases": ["Batman II", "The Tomorrow Knight", "The second Dark Knight", "The Dark Knight of Tomorrow", "Batman Beyond"],
            "place-of-birth": "Gotham City, 25th Century",
            "first-appearance": "Batman Beyond #1",
            "publisher": "DC Comics",
            "alignment": "good"
        },
        "appearance": {
            "gender": "Male",
            "race": "Human",
            "height": ["5'10", "178 cm"],
            "weight": ["170 lb", "77 kg"],
            "eye-color": "Blue",
            "hair-color": "Black"
        },
        "work": {
            "occupation": "-",
            "base": "21st Century Gotham City"
        },
        "connections": {
            "group-affiliation": "Batman Family, Justice League Unlimited",
            "relatives": "Bruce Wayne (biological father), Warren McGinnis (father, deceased), Mary McGinnis (mother), Matt McGinnis (brother)"
        },
        "image": {
            "url": "https:\/\/www.superherodb.com\/pictures2\/portraits\/10\/100\/10441.jpg"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "70",
        "name": "Batman",
        "powerstats": {
            "intelligence": "100",
            "strength": "26",
            "speed": "27",
            "durability": "50",
            "power": "47",
            "combat": "100"
        },
        "biography": {
            "full-name": "Bruce Wayne",
            "alter-egos": "No alter egos found.",
            "aliases": ["Insider", "Matches Malone"],
            "place-of-birth": "Crest Hill, Bristol Township; Gotham County",
            "first-appearance": "Detective Comics #27",
            "publisher": "DC Comics",
            "alignment": "good"
        },
        "appearance": {
            "gender": "Male",
            "race": "Human",
            "height": ["6'2", "188 cm"],
            "weight": ["210 lb", "95 kg"],
            "eye-color": "blue",
            "hair-color": "black"
        },
        "work": {
            "occupation": "Businessman",
            "base": "Batcave, Stately Wayne Manor, Gotham City; Hall of Justice, Justice League Watchtower"
        },
        "connections": {
            "group-affiliation": "Batman Family, Batman Incorporated, Justice League, Outsiders, Wayne Enterprises, Club of Heroes, formerly White Lantern Corps, Sinestro Corps",
            "relatives": "Damian Wayne (son), Dick Grayson (adopted son), Tim Drake (adopted son), Jason Todd (adopted son), Cassandra Cain (adopted ward)\nMartha Wayne (mother, deceased), Thomas Wayne (father, deceased), Alfred Pennyworth (former guardian), Roderick Kane (grandfather, deceased), Elizabeth Kane (grandmother, deceased), Nathan Kane (uncle, deceased), Simon Hurt (ancestor), Wayne Family"
        },
        "image": {
            "url": "https:\/\/www.superherodb.com\/pictures2\/portraits\/10\/100\/639.jpg"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "71",
        "name": "Batman II",
        "powerstats": {
            "intelligence": "88",
            "strength": "11",
            "speed": "33",
            "durability": "28",
            "power": "36",
            "combat": "100"
        },
        "biography": {
            "full-name": "Dick Grayson",
            "alter-egos": "Nightwing, Robin",
            "aliases": ["Dick Grayson"],
            "place-of-birth": "-",
            "first-appearance": "-",
            "publisher": "Nightwing",
            "alignment": "good"
        },
        "appearance": {
            "gender": "Male",
            "race": "Human",
            "height": ["5'10", "178 cm"],
            "weight": ["175 lb", "79 kg"],
            "eye-color": "Blue",
            "hair-color": "Black"
        },
        "work": {
            "occupation": "-",
            "base": "Gotham City; formerly Bludhaven, New York City"
        },
        "connections": {
            "group-affiliation": "Justice League Of America, Batman Family",
            "relatives": "John Grayson (father, deceased), Mary Grayson (mother, deceased), Bruce Wayne \/ Batman (adoptive father), Damian Wayne \/ Robin (foster brother), Jason Todd \/ Red Hood (adoptive brother), Tim Drake \/ Red Robin (adoptive brother), Cassandra Cain \/ Batgirl IV (adoptive sister)"
        },
        "image": {
            "url": "https:\/\/www.superherodb.com\/pictures2\/portraits\/10\/100\/1496.jpg"
        }
    }]
}
```

Here is the ouptut from my network tab

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in the browser's dev tools to see that the request was made? If the request is *actually* made then you like have *some* response. I don't see a `data`, or `totalItems` or `items` property in the JSON response snippet you shared.

Comment: I have shared the network tab screenshot

Comment: That shows there was an error, no character with the given name. I see now also in the `catch` block that you reset loading state true, was this intentional? How do you start your query parameter string?

Comment: i have changed that to false.Still getting the error.

Comment: FYI, a valid response can an error, this one being the name/character you were searching for not existing. This isn't necessarily a network request error.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first why you are using `setLoading(true);` with below block of code It should be `false`. As you said the loader never end then I think may be you are going in catch block.

```
.catch(err => {
          setLoading(true);
          console.log(err.response);
        });
```

Now if this is going to catch block then check your code with static api because it's not look any wrong in the code for now.

```
axios
        .get(`https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/my-api-key/search/batman`)
        .then(res => {
          console.log("response= ", res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          setLoading(true);
          console.log(err.response);
        });
```

If it's working it mean your query having issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not authenticated so I can't run these queries but if I had to guess I would say you aren't appending your query parameters correctly.

```
axios.get(`https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/my-api-key/search/${query}&maxResults=${maxResults}&startIndex=${startIndex}`)
```

It appears you are sending `"batman&maxResults=10&startIndex=1"` as the name you are searching for.

A correctly formatted query parameter string begins with the `?` character. So the request should probably look more like `https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/my-api-key/search/${query}?maxResults=${maxResults}&startIndex=${startIndex}` to form a name request with parameters as such `"batman?maxResults=10&startIndex=1"`.

The axios GET request code then would be

```
axios.get(`https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/my-api-key/search/${query}?maxResults=${maxResults}&startIndex=${startIndex}`)
```